# find the difference between two files and print it in the proper format

Tags: linux, text-processing

I have two text file "account.txt" and "customer.txt"

```
**account.txt**

876251251
716126181
888281211
666615211
787878787
111212134

**customer.txt**

876251251
716126181
792342108
792332668
666615211
760332429
791952441
676702288
```

I need to compare "account.txt" with "customer.txt".

- All account numbers from `account.txt` should be present in `customer.txt` file and if `customer.txt` is missing any "account number" then we should print out all those account numbers which are missing in `customer.txt`.
- And also all those extra customer numbers in `customer.txt` that are not present in `account.txt` file, I want to print that as well.

Output should be:

```
Missing Account Number:
888281211
787878787
111212134

Extra Customer Number:
792342108
792332668
760332429
791952441
676702288
```

Is this possible to do in linux? I started off like this but it only does the first case I want, not the second one? Also I need to print the output in the above format.

```
comm -23 account.txt customer.txt
```

**Note:** It could be possible that there are some strings or empty lines in those files so we need to discard that in the comparison if we see any. We only need to compare valid numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another simple option would be to use `comm`; it just needs sorted input, so give it clean input by filtering for "valid account numbers" (the whole line consists only of 9 digits), then pipe to sort before redirecting to a new file:

```
grep -Ex '[[:digit:]]{9}' account.txt   | sort > account.txt.sorted
grep -Ex '[[:digit:]]{9}' customer.txt  | sort > customer.txt.sorted
```

... then use `comm` as you indicated:

```
{ echo 'Missing Account Number:'; comm -23 account.txt.sorted customer.txt.sorted; }

{ echo 'Extra Customer Number:'; comm -13 account.txt.sorted customer.txt.sorted; }
```

Given sample inputs of:

## account.txt

```
garbage
876251251
716126181
888281211
666615211
666615211extra
787878787
111212134
extra
```

## customer.txt

```
garbage
876251251
876251251extra
716126181
792342108
792332668
666615211
760332429
791952441
676702288
junk
```

The resultant output is:

```
Missing Account Number:
111212134
787878787
888281211

Extra Customer Number:
676702288
760332429
791952441
792332668
792342108
```

Comment: I tried the first two grep command and in the two new files generated I only see one item? Any idea what could be the reason? Also can we remove the limitation that numbers can only be 9 digits? It can be more or less as well

Comment: It looks like first grep command is only returning one number as the output and that's why sorted file has one number in the file. not sure why though grep command gives one number as the output..

Comment: I assumed that account numbers were as you showed -- 9 digits, and by themselves on a line.

Comment: Some sample input would help; how do you distinguish an account number from not-an-account-number?

Comment: if it is a number then they are valid account or customer number. It can be more than 9 or less than 9 digits as well. Also `grep -Ex '[[:digit:]]{9}'` command is only returning one number in the output but in my .txt file I have lot of numbers...

Comment: Could you edit the question to demonstrate how the account numbers show up in the actual input? You can/should obfuscate them if they're real, of course, but then we can write usable answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, maybe easiest with `diff`.

```
$ diff account.txt customer.txt
1c1
< **account.txt**
---
> **customer.txt**
5c5,6
< 888281211
---
> 792342108
> 792332668
7,8c8,10
< 787878787
< 111212134
---
> 760332429
> 791952441
> 676702288

$ diff account.txt customer.txt|grep '^<'
< **account.txt**
< 888281211
< 787878787
< 111212134

$ diff account.txt customer.txt|grep '^>'
> **customer.txt**
> 792342108
> 792332668
> 760332429
> 791952441
> 676702288
```

---

The following shellscript `diff-script` is more polished.

```
#!/bin/bash

# assuming 9-digit account and customer numbers

sort account.txt  | uniq > account.srt
sort customer.txt | uniq > customer.srt

diff account.srt customer.srt > diff.txt

echo 'only in account.srt:' > result.txt
< diff.txt grep -E '^< [0-9]{9}$' | sed s'/^< //' >> result.txt

echo 'only in customer.srt:' >> result.txt
< diff.txt grep -E '^> [0-9]{9}$' | sed s'/^> //' >> result.txt

echo "The result is in the file 'result.txt'"
echo "You can read it with 'less result.txt'"
```

Demo example,

```
$ ./diff-script
The result is in the file 'result.txt'
You can read it with 'less result.txt'

$ cat result.txt 
only in account.srt:
111212134
787878787
888281211
only in customer.srt:
676702288
760332429
791952441
792332668
792342108
```

Comment: is there any way to do everything in one command and print in the above format?

Comment: @user5447339, I'll fine-tune my answer, please wait a while :-)

Comment: sure.. also how can I compare only valid numbers.. Ignore all the empty lines in the file and some strings as well which are there.. Also if you can add some description on how the above commands are working then it will help me a lot as well in understanding..

Comment: Please specify valid numbers! Are all nine-digit-numbers valid?

Comment: Sometimes I have some strings like `#REF!` or some other strings in a new line so it should discard those from the comparisons.. Also sometimes it has empty lines in the file followed by some numbers so it should discard those as well..

Comment: @user5447339, I think this shellscript will do the job for you.

Answer (score 0):

For this job i would choose awk. Bellow code runs only for valid data of 9 numbers in the row. Empty lines, lines with numbers more or less than 9, and lines with letters are ignored.

```
$ cat account
876251251

716126181
888281211
asdferfggggg
666615211
787878787
123456789123
111212134

$ cat customer
876251251
716126181
eeeeeeeee
792342108
792332668
666615211
760332429

791952441
676702288

$ awk '/^[0-9]{9}$/{a[$0]++;b[$0]="found only in " FILENAME}END{for (i in a) if (a[i]==1) print i,b[i]}' account customer |sort -k2
111212134 found only in account
787878787 found only in account
888281211 found only in account
676702288 found only in customer
760332429 found only in customer
791952441 found only in customer
792332668 found only in customer
792342108 found only in customer
```